# Не верю в людей, которые не сдаются

Tags: синтаксис

Извините, что ставлю такие вопросы, но не могу разобраться одна.

Пример:

> (1) Не верю в людей, **которые не сдаются.**

В моем языке стояло бы сослагательное наклонение, потому что наличие тех людей неконкретное, гипотетическое, может они есть, может их нет. Обнаружила, что есть сходство между нашими языками: если есть отрицание в главном предложении, в относительном придаточном стоит сослагательное наклонение ("*Ещё не родился тот мужчина, которого бы я испугалась*.") В таком случае не понимаю, почему (1) построено в индикативе. Не могли бы вы подтвердить или опровергнуть, то что я думаю, пожалуйста? Сделала следующий вывод: информация, которая стоит в относительном придаточном в (1), простой аттрибут к главному предложению, это просто "описательное" предложение и русский говорящий не фокусируется на том, существуют ли на самом деле такие люди, которые на сдаются; в центре сообщения стоит только то что он не верит. Или не так? =)

Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь возможны два варианта:

(1) **Обобщенное утверждение**, индикатив:

Не верю, что есть люди, которые **ничего не боятся**.

(2) **Конкретная гипотетическая ситуация,** сослагательное наклонение:

Не верю, что есть люди, которые **не испугались бы** в такой ситуации (если бы они оказались там).

Answer (score 2):

> > В таком случае не понимаю, почему (1) построено в индикативе

Да просто это плоховато построенная фраза, ее смысл примерно такой: эти люди не оправдают моих ожиданий. А вы ведь подразумеваете другой смысл: таких людей (которые не сдаются), по вашему мнению, не существует.